# Paypal IPN sending information if user made a payment or cancels a recurring payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm building a website that has a subscription functionality and I have a few question about Paypal IPN and recurring payment method.

Would the IPN be sent over to you if it is the due date for a recurring payment to be made?

**For example:**

User subscribed your product on September 1, then on October 2(payment due) the user made a payment(*automatic deduction via paypal's recurring payment*). Would an IPN be sent over on your server and tell you that this user has paid you?

And just a follow up question. If a user cancels his/her recurring payment, would an IPN sent over in your server so that you'll be able to know that he/she cancelled the recurring payment?

If No, how would I be able to know that the user has cancelled its payment?

Thanks! Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the answer is yes to all. PayPal will inform you whenever a payment is made, even if this payment is after a long time. (see [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments) at Recurring Payments Notifications section)

> PayPal notifies you of recurring payments events through IPN and
>   email. Typically, however, you can call GetTransactionDetails to
>   obtain the information you need.

Moreover PayPal sends IPN messages when a cancellation is beeing made.

However it's your responsibility to simulate and handle the diferent situations inside your php script in order to make sure when it's about a cancellation IPN message or a recurring payment.